# Woocommerce wc_create_new_customer override on checkout

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, user-accounts

I am using the guest checkout and have enabled **"Automatically generate username from customer email"** and **"Automatically generate customer password"**, also I created a hidden input
`<input class="input-checkbox" id="createaccount" <?php checked( ( true === $checkout->get_value( 'createaccount' ) || ( true === apply_filters( 'woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false ) ) ), true) ?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <label for="createaccount" class="checkbox"><?php _e( 'Create an account?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>` , which helps automatically create a user on checkout so customers didn't know that a user has been generated by their email. But if the same user, with the same email tries to fill the same email on the checkout field, receives the message: **"An account is already registered with your email address. Please login."** , which comes from `wc_create_new_customer` function inside the /woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php. 
I would like to override  `wc_create_new_customer` function and return the `$customer_id` for the existing user instead of firing and error for already registered account. Tried hooks and filters, but none of them works. Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing. Thanks!